# jQuery and Ajax to Return different set of data rather than creating seperate ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following jQuery setInterval function to reload data at 30 second intervals using ajax from a php file. I am running 3 different ajax calls in order to get 3 bits of information. Is there a way to consolidate the 3 seperate ajax calls into one call? 2 of the calls have the php file return back json data from session, and the other call just returns a number to display the quantity of unread messages.

Here is the jQuery code I currently have:

```
setInterval(function(){


jQuery.ajax({ url: '/ajax-msgs.php?check=1', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', cache: 'false', success: function(data) {
    var msghtml = '';
        jQuery.each(data, function() {
            msghtml += '<li><a href="message.php?id=' + this.msg_id + '">' + this.msg_subject + '</a></li>';
        });
        jQuery("#msg-menu").html(msghtml);
    }
});



jQuery.ajax({ url: '/ajax-msgs.php?check=2', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', cache: 'false', success: function(data) {
        jQuery.each(data, function() {
            jQuery.jGrowl(this.msg_title, { life: 12000});
        });
        }
    });



    jQuery.ajax({ url: '/ajax-msgs.php?check=3', type: 'POST', dataType: 'json', cache: 'false', success: function(data) {
            jQuery("#msg-count").text('87');
        }
    });


}, 30000);
```

And here is what the php file does:

```
if ($_GET['check']==1){

iMapFunction();
print_r(json_encode($_SESSION['message_overviews']));

} elseif ($_GET['check']==2){

iMapFunction();
print_r(json_encode($_SESSION['messages_new_notifications']));
unset($_SESSION['auth_messages_new_notifications']);

} elseif ($_GET['check']==3){

iMapFunction();
echo $_SESSION['messages_unread_count'];
}
```

Comment: Note that there is no reason to use `POST` on the Ajax call if you are using `$GET` on your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our PHP could return all the thata in one call like this:

```
<?php

iMapFunction();
$response = array(
 'message_overviews' => $_SESSION['message_overviews'],
 'messages_new_notifications' => $_SESSION['messages_new_notifications'],
 'messages_unread_count' => $_SESSION['messages_unread_count']
);

print_r(json_encode($response));

?>
```

And you can iterate on each data the same way you did before like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({ url: '/ajax-msgs.php', dataType: 'json', cache: 'false', success: function(data) {

        var message_overviews = data.message_overviews;
        var messages_new_notifications = data.messages_new_notifications;
        var messages_unread_count = data.messages_unread_count;
        var msghtml = '';

        jQuery.each(message_overviews, function() {
            msghtml += '<li><a href="message.php?id=' + this.msg_id + '">' + this.msg_subject + '</a></li>';
        });
        jQuery("#msg-menu").html(msghtml);

        jQuery.each(messages_new_notifications, function() {
            jQuery.jGrowl(this.msg_title, { life: 12000});
        });

        jQuery("#msg-count").text(messages_unread_count);

    }});

}, 30000);
```

Comment: seems to work well except the last part where the content of div id msg-count is supposed to read 87 in this example it doesnt. If i put that line of code outside the ajax call then it works, but inside the ajax call it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Has it got something to do with the fact that the other session values are arrays and $_SESSION['messages_unread_count'] is just a value?

Comment: If it is just a value the `$.each` will fail, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an endpoint that does all the actions in one call:

I don't know php but create an associative array and assign your data to that.

```
x = {};
x['message_overviews'] = $_SESSION['message_overviews'];
x['auth_messages'] = $_SESSION['auth_messages_new_notifications'];
x['messages_unread_count'] = $_SESSION['messages_unread_count'];
print_r(json_encode(x));
```

Then in your jquery response function you can access your data and do your actions:

```
function(data){
  console.log(data.message_overviews);
  console.log(data.auth_messages);
  console.log(data.messages_unread_count);
}
```